# Replacement for IRegisteredObject in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, timer, signalr, asp.net5

I am trying to build a simple ASP.NET 5 app with SignalR which should push messages to clients at regular intervals (e.g. implement a dashboard with values pushed from the server to the browser.)

I researched some posts such as http://arulselvan.net/realtime-dashboard-asp-net-signalr-angularjs-d3js/ or http://henriquat.re/server-integration/signalr/integrateWithSignalRHubs.html. They recommend implementing a timer in a class implementing `IRegisteredObject` from the `System.Web.Hosting` namespace.

However, I don't seem to be able to locate the namespace where `IRegisteredObject` lives in ASP.NET 5. `System.Web` no longer exists in ASP.NET 5.
I haven't been able to find any info on it online.
What is the substitute for it in ASP.NET 5?

**UPDATE**

I am trying the following solution:

- create a service encapsulating the timer
- register it in `Startup.cs` as a singleton service, e.g.

  ```
  public class Ticker
  {
      Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
      public Ticker()
      {
          timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
          timer.Start();
      }

      private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
        // do something
      }
  }
  ```

In `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ... 
        Ticker ticker = new Ticker();
        ServiceDescriptor sd = new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(Ticker), ticker);
        services.Add(sd);
        // ...
    }
```

How about this approach?

Comment: How about the `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` method? Was introduced with .NET 4.5 it replaces `IRegisteredObject`.

Comment: Nope, didn't find that either. It's in `System.Web.Hosting` - seems like this namespace doesn't exist anymore, like `System.Web` itself

Comment: about your update, there is notion of cancellation, a background job needs to complete when the app pool reycles.

Answer (score 8):

[`IRegisteredObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iregisteredobject(v=vs.110).aspx) basically just gives a way of notifying the implementing class of impending doom, once your instance is registered with [`HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.registerobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

In .net core there is no need to implement any interface. The corresponding method of `HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject` is [`IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.applicationstopping?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHostApplicationLifetime_ApplicationStopping).[`Register`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

In your application IoC, make sure to get a dependency on  [`IHostApplicationLifetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)    for an object or job manager or whatever to be able to register, or wire it up somehow in [Startup.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup) `Configure` method, where an instance of this interface can be accessed by the framework IoC:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    // Pipeline setup code ...

    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => { 
        // notify long-running tasks of pending doom  
    });
}
```

*Edit for asp.net core v2 and later*: The interface [`IHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice) and implementation [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice) should also be mentioned here, as it's a relevant alternative for the same scenario.

*Edit for asp.net core v3 and later*: The interface [`IApplicationLifetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is marked as obsolete (since ~3.0), use `IHostApplicationLifetime` for new development.